# How to manually upgrade Boost to latest version on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, ubuntu-22.04

A few months ago I installed boost on Ubuntu 22.04 using:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

This installed version 1.74. However, I need 1.82 and the 22.04 repositories do not contain 1.82.

I am aware of this page:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

but it mentions the installation path as `/usr/local`:

> Select your configuration options and invoke ./bootstrap.sh again
> without the --help option. Unless you have write permission in your
> system's /usr/local/ directory, you'll probably want to at least use

whereas my current installation on Ubuntu seems to be `/usr/include/boost/`?

Do I just download the tar to my `Downloads` and enter:

```
cd Downloads/boost_1_82_0
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/include/
```

?

So the emphasis on the question is, for Ubuntu should I use that prefix/is the above correct?

(Asking as I don't want to corrupt my existing environment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install boost-1.82 from Lauchpad PPA [Builds of latest releases of the C++ BOOST library](https://launchpad.net/%7Emhier/+archive/ubuntu/libboost-latest?field.series_filter=jammy).

Follow the manual from there.

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mhier/libboost-latest
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libboost
# or sudo apt install libboost1.82-dev
```

Comment: Unfortunately I got an error halfway through due to DPDK and now my installation seems corrupted. If you're able to help it would be greatly appreciated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76547317/boost-apt-update-failed-in-middle-due-to-dpdk-now-unsure-which-version-i-have

Comment: After the last command, I am getting this:

"E: Unable to locate package libboost"

Why?

Comment: @SasaMilenkovic That personal package archive doesn't seem to deal with the latest versions of boost. Try `sudo apt install boost1.81`. You can install the latest boost following this manual https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-boost-c-on-ubuntu-20-04-or-22-04/