# make command doesnt find library in include path

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, boost

I am very unfamiliar with c++, but I need to run a server written in it for a project. This project contains a `CMakeLists.txt`, which I "executed" with `cmake -Bbuild`.

In the `build` folder there then is a Makefile, which I "execute" with `make`.

Now, the compiler or whatever it is throws an error: `fatal error: boost/json.hpp: No such file or directory`

So `boost/json.hpp` doesn't seem to be included. I then installed boost manually according to [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) guide, and saved it into the directory `/usr/local/include/`.

Running `cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null` tells me, where it looks for included files. This is the result:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cpp
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:hsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,gm2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-9 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-9-9QDOt0/gcc-9-9.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,hsa --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' '/dev/null' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-gnu /dev/null -o /dev/null -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' '/dev/null' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

There is no `boost` file or directory in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/`, so according to my understanding, it should look in `/usr/local/include/` next, where it finds a `boost_1_82_0` directory with all the needed modules in the `boost` subdirectory, including `json`.

Still, the error mentioned above is thrown. As the project has been provided to me externally, I do not believe the error originates from the Makefile or anything like that. So why does it not seem to find the boost modules?

Comment: If `/usr/local/include` is in the include search path, it will look for `/usr/local/include/boost/json.hpp`. It doesn't search recursively. If you want to get at `/usr/local/include/boost_1_82.0/boost/json.hpp`, I think you will need `/usr/local/include/boost_1_82.0` in the include path. Also keep in mind that running `cpp` directly may have vastly different arguments to what happens in the `makefile` produced by `cmake`. It may be worth adding a debug rule into the `makefile` after it's created, one that basically does that command of yours but with the expected arguments.

Comment: Unless you are messing around with the internal of boost don't install it manually. Use the appropriate package manager for your platform: Linux like `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev`.  Mac like `brew install boost`

Answer (score 1):

CMake is the program that "builds" the makefile. If it's in the project (and it is) you shouldn't really touch the makefile itself as CMake overwrites the generated makefile if it is ran again. The foolproof way of making things run for your setup should be: 0. deleting Boost files you manually placed anywhere 1. getting boost by installing it with your package manager (e.g. `sudo apt install libboost-all-dev`) 2. ensuring that one of your CMakeLists.txt (there can be multiple files with this name) contains something like these lines:

```
FIND_PACKAGE( Boost 1.83 REQUIRED )

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

ADD_EXECUTABLE( your_program yourmain.cpp )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( your_program PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

The step 2. should not be necessary if the project builds on other machines. But for further explanation:
`FIND_PACKAGE` finds the boost installment and set `Boost_INCLUDE_DIR` `Boost_LIBRARIES` variables. Then, `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` command passes the header files' locations and `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` passes linker info to makefile with which `make` should run smoothly further on.

EDIT:
To install the latest version of boost you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76543551/4938358):

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mhier/libboost-latest
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libboost
```

Or for specific version of boost e.g. 1.82.0:

```bash
sudo apt-get install libboost-dev= 1.82.0.1
```

(I'm not sure about the last digit tough)

Comment: I did install `libboost-all-dev`, but its version was too outdated (1.71), as the project I am working with requires the newest version. How would I go about installing the newest version (1.83 or 1.82 would also suffice), if I shouln't do it manually?

Comment: Checkout edit in the answer

Comment: I could not install libboost this way, I received an error about how the package was missing. I looked into the link you provided, where a comment contained a link to this [instruction](https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-install-boost-c-on-ubuntu-20-04-or-22-04/). With this I could install the newest boost... not *entirely* manually. Building the Makefile still errors, but now it's something vastly different, something about a bit not being declared in this scope. It feels very specific to the project, and I am thus contacting the developers about it